# How can i make this kind of View (from iPhone) in Android?

Tags: iphone, android, user-interface, listview

I am porting an app from iPhone to Android and I was wondering what the best way was to make this screen in Android?

[image]

The places where it sais "optioneel" and where the phonenumbers are must be editable like this:

[image]

This is what I've come up with so far:

[image]

So how can I make these 'editable listview' things in Android?

Comment: How did you do it on the iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a normal [EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) element and apply a plain white images as background.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a specialist in porting iPhone apps to Android. I have my own library of iOS-style widgets for Android. I can't give you source code but I'll give you a clue: use `EditText` for the editable ones, obviously with a custom background nine-patch. You can override `dispatchDraw()` to draw the label on the left, and set the left padding so it doesn't clash with the user-provided text.

Comment: I'm not that into copying UI's. I'd like to keep every phone to it's own UI-library. An iPhone is an iPhone and Android is an Android.

But nevertheless I'm very interested in your library :)

Comment: Fair enough. I just like UI to look great, and unfortunately iOS presently leads when it comes to widget sexiness. My customers also seem happier when their Android port looks just like their iPhone product (within reason). It also keeps costs way down if they don't have to develop a 2nd load of image assets.

Comment: That's true, but doesn't your source get 'loggy'? And does it have to same look at different screen sizes? That is mainly the reason I want to use controls the Android SDK delivers

Comment: Nope, performance suffers not a jot. In fact it's generally better. For example, I use OpenGL for my maps, a choice which delivers a massive performance boost over the standard MapView. I also have my own layout animation magic helpers, because doing fancy iOS-style layout animations on Android is very slow and problematic. But we're drifting off the point now. :)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create a [TableView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html) and then add a Label on the left hand column and a TextView / EditText in the right hand column. Correctly styled this would match the form and function of the iPhone app.